# Footer overlaps contents in mobile view

Tags: html, css, wordpress, footer

The footer of my webiste works fine in desktop view but it is overlapping the conents of body on it. I am using wordpress for this website. You can check out the site [here](http://www.shop2trip.in/)
I am not sure what exactly the code is with mistake so I am not uploading my code here. Please look at the live site and help me out.

Comment: please add your codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove height:100%; from this class ".rsrc-content".